# Unable to get the SEVERE exception in Logs in Java - different output in Eclipse and Netbeans

Tags: java, exception, logging, handler

Want to capture the Severe Logs. However different outputs in two IDEs. Unable to understand the error.Attached the output pictures

- [Output shown in Netbeans](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7PFm.png)
- [Different output in Eclipse for the same code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1b1Z.jpg)

```java
private LaunchScheduler() throws ParseException, IOException, InterruptedException { 

    createLog(logfname+"//");    // Invalid filename- returns a severe message
    createLog(logfname);        // valid log handler creation
}

void createLog(String logname) throws InterruptedException {

    try {
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
        Handler fileHandler = new FileHandler(logname,5000,1);
        logger.addHandler(fileHandler);
        logger.info("Create a file and returning the handler");
    } catch (IOException |InterruptedException ex){
        logger.severe("Can't create file Handler");
    } 
}
```

Comment: Please show the error outputs directly here in your question and not through external links.

Comment: Please suggest how do I paste it here. I tried but unable to do so. Are you not able to click on the links?

Comment: Do not paste it as picture, but as text. Both (eclipse and netbeans) can copy the error messages as text. Pasting as text also has the advantage that it can be analyzed by search engines.

Comment: @Constant_Learning Include the exception message and print the `logname` that gets passed to `FileHandler`.  Also print the Java version running your code.  You might be running into [a known bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46980752/missing-slash-on-java-9-s-logmanager-getlogger-logger-gethandlers-seems-to/46983482#46983482).

Comment: @ a known bug...will try and confirm. Thank you.